# API call to calendar.events.list failed with error: Sync token is no longer valid, a full sync is required. What should i do?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

i get an error regarding sync token not valid and required full sync. What should i add in the code to fix it
?

- Multiple google calendar events to google sheet using google appscript

I try to read Google Calendar API but i don't know where to change in the code.

This is some of the code for sync token.

```
function updateSyncToken(calendarId, syncToken) {
  var spreadsheetId = 'sheetID';
  if(calendarId == 'Cal1') {
    var range = 'Settings!B2';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal2') {
    var range = 'Settings!B3';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal3') {
    var range = 'Settings!B4';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal4') {
    var range = 'Settings!B5';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal5') {
    var range = 'Settings!B6';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal6') {
    var range = 'Settings!B7';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal7') {
    var range = 'Settings!B8';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal8') {
    var range = 'Settings!B9';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal9') {
    var range = 'Settings!B10';
  } else if(calendarId == 'Cal10') {
    var range = 'Settings!B11';
  } else {
    return
  }
  var values = [[syncToken]];

  var valueRange = Sheets.newRowData();
  valueRange.values = values;

  var appendRequest = Sheets.newAppendCellsRequest();
  appendRequest.sheetId = spreadsheetId;
  appendRequest.rows = [valueRange];

  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, {
    valueInputOption: 'RAW'
  });
}

function fetchEvents(calendarId, syncToken, sheetId) {
  var options = {
    syncToken: syncToken 
  }; 
  var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, options);
  var events = response.items;
  if (events.length > 0) {
    updateSyncToken(calendarId, response.nextSyncToken)
    logEvents(events, sheetId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#410_gone).

> **Suggested action**: For SyncToken or updatedMin parameters, wipe the store and re-sync. For more details see [Synchronize Resources
>   Efficiently](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync). For
>   already deleted events, no further action is necessary.

You may also find more literature with [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33202606/10713297).